# Error trying to run geb tests with cucumber-jvm

Tags: grails, groovy, geb, cucumber-jvm

I am trying to get some geb tests running in a Grails project within IntelliJ but am having trouble & after 2 days of web searching & trying different things am still stuck.  We did have some Groovy tests running fine, previously, but no luck so far with geb.  We're using cucumber-jvm.

Currently I am getting the following error:
    Error Error executing script TestApp: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: 
    No signature of method: GebConfig.environments() is applicable for argument types:
    (GebConfig$_run_closure2) values: [GebConfig$_run_closure2@4ad3727e]

My GebConfig.groovy file is in test/functional, and contains:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver

// Use htmlunit as the default
// See: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/HtmlUnitDriver
driver = {
    def driver = new HtmlUnitDriver()
    driver.javascriptEnabled = true
    driver
}

environments {Not sure 
    chrome {-Dgeb.env=chrome
        driver = { new ChromeDriver() }
    }
    firefox {
        driver = { new FirefoxDriver() }
    }
}
```

I have the .feature file also in test/functional.  The step def's are in test/functional/steps & contains:

```
package steps

import geb.*

this.metaClass.mixin (cucumber.runtime.groovy.EN)
this.metaClass.mixin (cucumber.runtime.groovy.Hooks)

def browser = new Browser()

Given (~"I am on the front page") {
    browser.go("http://localhost:8081/whereisOne")
}
```

There is also a shared_driver.groovy class in test/functional/setup that was created for the straight Groovy tests, & I'm not sure if this is still needed.

The run config command is:  test-app --stacktrace, with VM options:  -Dgeb.env=chrome

Any help appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Just noticed the "Not sure" after environment closure start brace - that's not actually in the code!

Comment: I've got around this issue by commenting out the environment{} section in GebConfig.groovy, which seemed to be a problem going by the error given.

All good now.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: Why use cucumber when the geb-spock integration is so much more well documented?

Answer (score 0):

Is the -Dgeb.env=chrome in the code? If so, you have to remove this line. Everything else looks fine.